# td-agent2 shows warning: WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset: json (>= 1.4.3)

Tags: fluentd, treasure-data

td-agent2 shows warning below:

```
# sudo /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluent-gem list
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      json (>= 1.4.3)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
(snip)
```

I try to fix this by `sudo /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluent-gem cleanup`, but this command does not fix the warning.

Is this no problem?

```
# td-agent --version
td-agent 0.12.7

# apt-cache show td-agent
Package: td-agent
Status: install ok installed
Priority: extra
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 207309
Maintainer: Treasure Data, Inc
Architecture: amd64
Version: 2.2.0-0
Description: Treasure Agent: A data collector for Treasure Data
Description-md5: 9a8c3c5185974525f7e38d7f37f5d597
License: unknown
Vendor: Omnibus <omnibus@getchef.com>
Homepage: http://treasuredata.com

# sudo /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluent-gem --version
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      json (>= 1.4.3)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
2.2.1

# Ubuntu 14.04
```

https://gist.github.com/sanemat/09e5d995d9c607054dad

Answer (score 3):

#### The Problem

It looks like there are *conflicting gem versions* of **`json`**:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      json (>= 1.4.3)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
```

---

#### Fix the problem with [Bundler](https://bundler.io/)

If you use Bundler, you should see this problem go away.

#### Fix the problem with `gem cleanup` ([RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/))

Otherwise, try `gem cleanup` (doesn't often work correctly):

```
$ gem cleanup json
Cleaning up installed gems...
Clean Up Complete
```

#### Fix the problem with `gem uninstall` ([RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/))

Or try to uninstall some `json` gems you don't use it anymore:

```
$ gem uninstall json

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. json-1.4.3
 2. json-1.8.2
 3. json-1.8.3
 4. All versions
> 1
Successfully uninstalled json-1.4.3
```